# MongoDB not downloading database with Compass

Tags: mongodb

Having an issue with the following:

After connecting to a cluster from MongoDB Compass, it shows the name of the database but the information is 0. Storage size, Collections, and Index are at zero.

On the web-browser I can see the data, but with Compass I cannot. I have the latest version downloaded from today from the date of this post and am still having problem with this.

Comment: You connected to a wrong database.

Comment: Hi, no it was not a wrong database. The issue was the privilege of the IP was not whitelisted. Once this was fixed, I was able to connect to the database and see the contents of it.

Comment: You didn't connect successfully then.

Comment: Doesn't really say why this happens, or how to solve it. My account was changed to admin but it still didn't work. It was not the configuration settings that were the issue. I was able to connect to the database but was not able to see/download contents from the database with Compass. On the web I was able to see the contents.

Comment: If you didn't have your IP whitelisted, you did not connect successfully. Either you misinterpreted the UI or the UI didn't clearly state what was going on, but you didn't connect.